# Implementing PyQt5 "docking/undocking" mechamism for QStackedWidget: unpredictable Access Violation

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5

I'm using PyQt5 and i'm trying to make a mechanism for **docking/undocking** QWidgets from QStackedWidget (i have a QComboBox/QStackedWidget working together + QPushButton for current widget undocking). I know about QDockWidgets, but it seems it's impossible to locate them in central widget of QMainWindow, especially put them into QStackedWidget.

When user is clicking on button, current widget's flags are changing to Qt.Window - after then show() method calls. When user closes docked widget (window), the widget returns back to QStackedWidget.

To automate QPushButton clicking i also wrote the imitate() slot for QTimer: it undocks several DockWidgets (imitates user click on QPushButton), then closes them and repeats.

There is a Python code reproducing my idea:

```
from typing import NoReturn
from typing import Optional

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

import enum


class ImitatorStatus(enum.IntEnum):
    Undocking: int = enum.auto()
    Docking:   int = enum.auto()


class DockWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """Test QWidget with docking/undocking feature"""
    # Signal emitting when docked window closes
    returnToQStackedWidgetSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, index: int, parent: Optional[QtWidgets.QWidget] = None):
        super(DockWidget, self).__init__(parent, flags=Qt.Widget)
        self.setObjectName("item%d" % index)

        self.vLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Item no. %d" % index, self)
        self.label.setObjectName("label%d" % index)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignRight)
        self.label.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        palette = self.label.palette()
        palette.setColor(self.label.backgroundRole(), QtGui.QColor("#ffa100"))
        self.label.setPalette(palette)

        self.vLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.vLayout)

        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 450))
        # self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_QuitOnClose, True)

    def show(self) -> NoReturn:
        # There i'm changing windowFlags, and PyQt5 provides
        # a separate QWindow to show this DockWidget
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window)
        super(DockWidget, self).show()

    def closeEvent(self, event: QtGui.QCloseEvent) -> NoReturn:
        # noinspection PyTypeChecker
        if self.windowFlags() & Qt.Window:
            # Change windowFlags back to Qt.QWidget
            self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Widget)
            super(DockWidget, self).closeEvent(event)
            self.returnToQStackedWidgetSignal.emit()
        else:
            super(DockWidget, self).closeEvent(event)


# noinspection PyPep8Naming
class DockWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DockWindow, self).__init__(flags=Qt.Window)
        self.setObjectName("DockWindow")

        self._centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self._centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)

        # QPushButton for undocking current widget from QStackedWidget
        self.undockButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("UNDOCK", self)
        self.undockButton.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.undockButton.setObjectName("undockButton")
        self.undockButton.setCheckable(False)

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")

        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self._centralWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.undockButton, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget, 1, 0, 1, 2)

        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.gridLayout)

        self._count = 20
        for i in range(self._count):
            text = "Item %d" % i
            self.comboBox.addItem(text)

            dock_widget = DockWidget(i, self)
            dock_widget.returnToQStackedWidgetSignal.connect(self.backToQStackedWidgetSlot)
            self.stackedWidget.addWidget(dock_widget)

            setattr(self, "item%d" % i, dock_widget)

        self.undockButton.clicked.connect(self.undockButtonClicked)
        # QComboBox and QStackedWidget are working tohether
        self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged[int].connect(self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex)

        minimum_size = QtCore.QSize(1000, 750)
        self.setMinimumSize(minimum_size)
        self.resize(minimum_size)

        # Constants for "click imitator"
        self.imitator_state = ImitatorStatus.Undocking
        self.count_of_windows = 5

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.setTimerType(Qt.PreciseTimer)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.imitate)
        # Uncomment the next string to start automate test
        # timer.start(200)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def undockButtonClicked(self):
        if self.stackedWidget.count() == 1:
            # QStackedWidget should contain at least one QWidget
            self.sender().setEnabled(False)
            return

        widget = self.stackedWidget.currentWidget()  # type: DockWidget
        text = self.comboBox.currentText()

        self.comboBox.removeItem(self.comboBox.currentIndex())
        self.stackedWidget.removeWidget(widget)

        # Calling overriden (DockWidget.show) method
        widget.setWindowTitle(text)
        widget.show()
        widget.setGeometry(QtWidgets.QStyle.alignedRect(
            Qt.LeftToRight,
            Qt.AlignVCenter | Qt.AlignLeft,
            widget.size(),
            QtWidgets.qApp.desktop().availableGeometry()
        ))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def backToQStackedWidgetSlot(self):
        widget = self.sender()  # type: DockWidget

        # Returning widget back to QStackedWidget
        # and append appropriate item in QComboBox
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(widget)
        self.comboBox.addItem(f"Returned widget: {widget.objectName()}")

        if not self.undockButton.isEnabled():
            self.undockButton.setEnabled(True)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def imitate(self):
        if self.imitator_state is ImitatorStatus.Undocking:
            # This string imitates user click on QPushButton
            self.undockButton.click()
        else:
            # Testing dock mechanism
            for window in QtWidgets.QApplication.allWindows():
                # QWindow`s object name is "item\d{1,2}Window"
                if "item" in window.objectName():
                    # returnToQStackedWidgetSignal emitting
                    window.close()
                    break

        self.count_of_windows -= 1
        if not self.count_of_windows:
            # Changing imitator state
            self.imitator_state = (ImitatorStatus.Docking
                                   if self.imitator_state is ImitatorStatus.Undocking
                                   else ImitatorStatus.Undocking)
            self.count_of_windows = 5


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Without faulthandler module
    # application silently crash
    import faulthandler
    faulthandler.enable()

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    dock_window = DockWindow()
    dock_window.show()

    status = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(status)
```

So this code is working except one thing - sometimes it silently crashes. With enabled **faulthandler** module it crashes with next error:

```
Windows fatal exception: access violation

Current thread 0x00001e38 (most recent call first):
  File "_stackoverflow_docker.py", line 165 in imitate
  File "_stackoverflow_docker.py", line 189 in <module>
Segmentation fault
```

When i'm testing this manually, only 2nd stack frame appears because close() method calls non-programmatically.

I have no idea how to debug this error. Moreover, it looks like this error raised randomly: after closing 1st undock window or 101th... This behavior is very strange.

Being desperate i decided to duplicate this code in Qt Creator using C++ (it's my first C++ code, so please don't judge the quality of it) and IT WORKS! This code works just as expected:

***dockwidget.h***

```
#ifndef DOCKWIDGET_H
#define DOCKWIDGET_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>

class DockWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DockWidget(int index, QWidget *parent = 0);

    QLabel *label;

    void show();

protected:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event);

signals:
    // Signal emitting when docked window closes
    void returnToQStackedWidgetSignal();

public slots:
};

#endif // DOCKWIDGET_H
```

***dockwidget.cpp***

```
#include "dockwidget.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPalette>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSizePolicy>
#include <QStackedWidget>

DockWidget::DockWidget(int index, QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setObjectName(QString("item%1").arg(QString::number(index)));

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

    label = new QLabel(QString("Item no. %1").arg(QString::number(index)), this);
    label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignRight);
    label->setAutoFillBackground(true);

    QPalette pal = palette();
    pal.setColor(label->backgroundRole(), QColor("#ffa100"));
    label->setPalette(pal);

    layout->addWidget(label);
    setLayout(layout);

    setMinimumSize(QSize(600, 450));
    // setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, true);
}

void DockWidget::show()
{
    // There i'm changing windowFlags, and PyQt5 provides
    // a separate QWindow to show this DockWidget
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
    QWidget::show();
}

void DockWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event) {
    if (windowFlags() & Qt::Window) {
        // Change windowFlags back to Qt.QWidget
        setWindowFlags(Qt::Widget);
        QWidget::closeEvent(event);
        emit returnToQStackedWidgetSignal();
    } else {
        QWidget::closeEvent(event);
    }
}
```

***mainwindow.h***

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QStackedWidget>

enum ImitatorStatus {Undocking, Docking};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    QStackedWidget *stackedWidget;
    QComboBox *comboBox;
    QPushButton *undockButton;

    int _count = 20;
    int countOfWindows;
    ImitatorStatus imitatorState;

private slots:
    void undockButtonClicked();
    void backToStackedWidgetSlot();
    void imitate();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

***mainwindow.cpp***

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "dockwidget.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QSizePolicy>
#include <QStackedWidget>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QWindow>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget *_centralWidget = new QWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(_centralWidget);

    // QPushButton for undocking current widget from QStackedWidget
    undockButton = new QPushButton("UNDOCK", this);
    undockButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
    undockButton->setObjectName("undockButton");
    undockButton->setCheckable(false);

    comboBox = new QComboBox(this);
    comboBox->setObjectName("comboBox");

    stackedWidget = new QStackedWidget(this);
    stackedWidget->setObjectName("stackedWidget");

    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(_centralWidget);
    layout->addWidget(comboBox, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    layout->addWidget(undockButton, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    layout->addWidget(stackedWidget, 1, 0, 1, 2);

    _centralWidget->setLayout(layout);

    for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++) {
        QString string = QString("Item %1").arg(QString::number(i));
        comboBox->addItem(string);

        DockWidget *widget = new DockWidget(i, this);
        QObject::connect(widget, SIGNAL(returnToQStackedWidgetSignal()), this, SLOT(backToStackedWidgetSlot()));
        stackedWidget->addWidget(widget);
    }

    QObject::connect(undockButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(undockButtonClicked()));
    // QComboBox and QStackedWidget are working tohether
    QObject::connect(comboBox, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), stackedWidget, SLOT(setCurrentIndex(int)));

    QSize minimum_size(1000, 750);
    setMinimumSize(minimum_size);
    resize(minimum_size);

    // Constants for "click imitator"
    imitatorState = Undocking;
    countOfWindows = 5;

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setTimerType(Qt::PreciseTimer);
    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(imitate()));
    timer->start(200);

    qDebug() << "Qt version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}


void MainWindow::undockButtonClicked() {
    // qDebug() << "Button clicked";
    if (stackedWidget->count() == 1) {
        // QStackedWidget should contain at least one QWidget
        undockButton->setEnabled(false);
        return;
    }

    DockWidget* widget = qobject_cast<DockWidget*>(stackedWidget->currentWidget());
    QString text = comboBox->currentText();

    comboBox->removeItem(comboBox->currentIndex());
    stackedWidget->removeWidget(widget);

    // Calling overriden (DockWidget.show) method
    widget->setWindowTitle(text);
    widget->show();
    widget->setGeometry(QStyle::alignedRect(
                            Qt::LeftToRight,
                            Qt::AlignVCenter | Qt::AlignLeft,
                            widget->size(),
                            qApp->desktop()->availableGeometry()));
}

void MainWindow::backToStackedWidgetSlot() {
    DockWidget *widget = qobject_cast<DockWidget*>(sender());

    // Returning widget back to QStackedWidget
    // and append appropriate item in QComboBox
    stackedWidget->addWidget(widget);
    comboBox->addItem(QString("Returned widget: %1").arg(widget->objectName()));

    if (!undockButton->isEnabled()) {
        undockButton->setEnabled(true);
    }
}

void MainWindow::imitate() {
    if (imitatorState == Undocking) {
        // This string imitates user click on QPushButton
        undockButton->click();

    } else {
        // Testing dock mechanism
        QWindowList windows = qApp->allWindows();
        for (int i = 0; i < windows.size(); ++i) {
            QWindow *window = windows.at(i);
            QString objectName = window->objectName();
            // QWindow`s object name is "item\d{1,2}Window"
            if (objectName.indexOf("item") != -1) {
                // returnToQStackedWidgetSignal emitting
                window->close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    countOfWindows--;
    if (!countOfWindows) {
        // Changing imitator state
        imitatorState = (imitatorState == Undocking)? Docking: Undocking;
        countOfWindows = 5;
    }
}
```

My only guess was that Python-reference to one of DockWidgets is deleting at runtime, and i added this string (lineno. 99 in code):

```
setattr(self, "item%d" % i, widget)
```

Also i tried this:

```
self._count = 6

self.comboBox.addItem("Item 0")

self.item0 = DockWidget(0, self)
self.item0.returnToQStackedWidgetSignal.connect(self.backToQStackedWidgetSlot)
self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.item0)

...

self.comboBox.addItem("Item 5")

self.item5 = DockWidget(5, self)
self.item5.returnToQStackedWidgetSignal.connect(self.backToQStackedWidgetSlot)
self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.item5)
```

But both changed didn't help me at all - it still crashes with access violation...

I ran this Python code on Python 3.7.2 (win32), PyQt version - 5.12. For running C++ code i used Qt Creator 4.13.1 (based on Qt 5.15.1, also Windows x32).

P.S. It's my very first answer on Stackoverflow, so i apologize in advance if i forgot to mention something important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by myself after reimplementing DockWidget.closeEvent method:

```
def closeEvent(self, event: QtGui.QCloseEvent) -> NoReturn:
    if self.windowFlags() & Qt.Window:
        # Change windowFlags back to Qt.QWidget
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Widget)
        # We need to ignore QCloseEvent here
        event.ignore()
        self.returnToQStackedWidgetSignal.emit()
    else:
        event.accept()
```